# How to remove unbreaking space from a string in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I wonder how to remove unbreaking space chr(160) from a string in VBA.
I tried

```
s = replace(s, chr(160), " ")
```

but it gives not success... The unbreaking spaces are still here...

I wrote this which works but it's so slow on numerous long strings that I have to manage...

```
Public Function RectifySpaces(s As String) As String
  Dim i As Long, ln As Long, c As String
  ln = Len(s)
  RectifySpaces = ""
  For i = 1 To ln
    c = Mid$(s, i, 1)
    If Asc(c) = 160 Then
      RectifySpaces = RectifySpaces & " "
    Else
      RectifySpaces = RectifySpaces & c
    End If
  Next
End Function
```

Any hint  on how to use replace properly ? I must miss something because I saw some solutions with "replace" on the web...

Comment: You may need to validate if `Chr(160)` in your string with `For i=1 To Len(s): Debug.Print Asc(Mid(s,i,1)): Next`.

Comment: you do not show your original code for the replace. so we can not see if there is a typing error.

Comment: `replace(s, chr(160), " ")` works fine, so there's something else going on which we can't see.  Please update to show your full code (or at least a minimum code which replicates the problem).  If your second code does what you need then there's something about how your `Replace()` flow.